# Axis scaling issue with matlab2tikz

Tags: pgfplots, plot, matlab2tikz

I use [`matlab2tikz`](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz) to efficiently save `Matlab` plots as vector graphics for `latex` documents. I have axis scaling issues compared to the `Matlab` plot and the one rendered in my document.

The plot from `Matlab` looks like this:
[image]

However the plot rendered using `matlab2tikz` and inside `latex` appears like this:
[image].

Since I do not know the aspect ratio of the plot, I see both `\figureheight`
and `\figurewidth` equal. I have two questions:

1. How to maintain aspect ratio as it is in Matlab, as the ellipse's aspect ratio needs to represented accurately?
2. Both the x-and y-axes are overflowing (whitespace around the shaded plot). How to avoid this?

Comment: For 1., if you *don't* specify the width and height in the call to `matlab2tikz`, does that give you the correct aspect ratio? For 2., see if adding `enlargelimits=false` to the `axis` options in the generated  file helps.

Comment: For 1: I did not specify the width and height. Then, I get equal axis scales. However, the image is too large in tex document. I tried to scale it down. Then the plot fonts also decrease. For 2: It works! Please post it as answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using something like

```matlab
matlab2tikz('filename.tex','width','\figwidth','extraAxisOptions','enlargelimits=false')
```

when you call `matlab2tikz`. It appears that when you only specify the `width` like this, the `height` is set as a fraction of `\figwidth` as well, so you can keep that aspect ratio. `enlargelimits=false` should remove the whitespace around the plot.